# Install Odoo 15 No module named 'babel'

Tags: installation, odoo-15

Dicide to use odoo 15. It need python v3.7 - ok install v3.7. Try to run but have error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel'"`
Then use

```
(venv) rmax@rmax-comp:~/odoo/odoo15$ pip install babel
Requirement already satisfied: babel in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from babel) (2019.3)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal -- sudo pip3 install babel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

activate virtual environment: source /bin/activate

then

sudo pip3 install babel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).